# How to know the direction of rotation of a body?

Tags: rotational-kinematics

I have a doubt that does the net torque on a body gives the sense of rotation of the body,i.e, clockwise rotation or anticlockwise rotation,or does it only give the sense of angular acceleration of the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The torque is equal to the rate of change of the angular momentum, and therefore related to the rate of change of the angular velocity. It is *not* related to the angular velocity itself. The torque can easily be in the opposite direction from the angular velocity, and thus opposite the direction of rotation.

For example, suppose you have a Tibetan prayer wheel spinning clockwise. If you exert a counter-clockwise torque on it, it will start to spin more slowly, but it will still spin for a while in the clockwise direction before starting to spin counter-clockwise.

This is just like how force determines acceleration, not velocity. When you throw a ball into the air, it moves in the opposite direction of the downward gravitational force for a while before falling.

In general, you need to integrate the equations of motion, from some initial state, to determine how a body moves under a force or a torque.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. The fact that torque is made of a vector product gives a lot of information. In particular, the direction of the torque indicates both the magnitude and the sense of rotation.

You probably know the right hand rule:

[image: Right hand rule (1)]

*Note: I couldn't upload a more suitable one. Change "magnetic field" for "radius", "current" for "force", and "motion" for "torque"*.

However, There is another "version" of this right hand rule. This one:

[image]

Again, this is referred to a magnetic field, but the position is the same.

Place your thub along the torque.

Your fingers roll around circles in the sense of motion.

Consequently, a torque upwards means counterclockwise circulation (seen from above).

Negative torque (downwards) implies clockwise movement (seen from above). Check it out with the right hand rule.

Comment: But if we consider a sphere rolling up the plane then forces acting on it are weight and friction which have torque anticlockwise direction but the sphere is moving in clockwise direction

Comment: This consideration gives you how the torque **tends** to move the object. If the object is spinning in the clockwise direction, but it has a net torque anti-clockwise; then the ball will progressively stop and spin backwards. In fact, torque is related to angular acceleration, not angular velocity itself.

Answer (score 0):

The net torque on a body will cause the angular acceleration of the body.

I assume we are talking about a human body. Let's for simplicity consider a case when a man, blindfolded, is standing in the middle of a platform, which is starting to accelerate clockwise from the initial resting state.

In this case, the torque will be applied to the body as a pair of static friction forces, one of the forces will push the left foot forward, the other - the right foot backward.

Just by sensing these forces, the man would be able to guess that he is undergoing a clockwise angular acceleration, because he would not feel any other external forces that could possibly prevent that acceleration.

But he would not need to guess, since the angular acceleration will cause a twisting stress on the body and the man would be able to feel it as clockwise directed pressure forces throughout his body. In addition, he would need to shift the weight and engage certain groups of muscles to prevent the fall, which should give him another cue.

Similar logic should be applicable to other body positions and torque application points. It would be also applicable if the platform was already rotating, clockwise or counterclockwise, before it started to accelerate or decelerate.

Besides the twisting forces, associated with the angular acceleration, the man would experience centrifugal forces. Since centrifugal forces are directed radially, they would indicate the velocity of the rotation but not the direction of the acceleration. Once the acceleration stops, the twisting forces would go away, but the centrifugal forces will persist as long as the platform is spinning.